# Dart Print statement Difference

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dart

[two different output of print function in dart language]

Code Example 1 --------

```
var growablelist = List.filled(0, 0, growable: true);
growablelist.add(5);
growablelist.add(36);
growablelist.add(64);
print(growablelist);
growablelist.remove(36);
print(growablelist);
growablelist.removeAt(0);
print(growablelist);
```

output - [5, 36, 64], [5, 64], [64]

Code Example 2----------

```
var growablelist = List.filled(0, 0, growable: true);
growablelist.add(5);
growablelist.add(36);
growablelist.add(64);
print(growablelist);
print(growablelist.remove(36));
print(growablelist.removeAt(0));
```

output - [5, 36, 64], true, 5

I'm expecting the same output.
But what's the wrong??
Please clear me…

Comment: Read the documentation, check what remove and removeAt return

Comment: because of its return type showing different outputs

Answer (score 1):

Code Example 1:

step 1: initialize variable by default growable true

```
    var growablelist = List.filled(0, 0, growable: true);
```

2. adding 5  to growablelist list, now list will be [5]

   ```
   growablelist.add(5);
   ```

3.adding 36  to growablelist  list, now the list will be [5, 36]

```
  growablelist.add(36);
```

4.adding 64 to growablelist  list, now the list will be [5, 36,64]

```
 growablelist.add(64);
```

5. print growablelist which has list values [5, 36,64]

   ```
    print(growablelist);
   ```
6. removing 36 value from the growablelist list, now the list will be [5,64]

   ```
       growablelist.remove(36);
   ```
7. print growablelist which has list values [5,64]

   ```
       print(growablelist);
   ```
8. remove the item at index '0' from growablelist, now the list will be [64]

   ```
      growablelist.removeAt(0);
   ```
9. print growablelist which has list values [64]

   ```
      print(growablelist);
   ```

Now, code example 2:

step 1: initialize variable by default growable true

```
    var growablelist = List.filled(0, 0, growable: true);
```

2. adding 5  to growablelist list, now list will be [5]

   ```
    growablelist.add(5);
   ```
3. adding 36  to growablelist  list, now the list will be [5, 36]

   ```
    growablelist.add(36);
   ```
4. adding 64 to growablelist  list, now the list will be [5, 36,64]

   ```
    growablelist.add(64);
   ```
5. print growablelist which has list values [5, 36,64]

   ```
    print(growablelist);
   ```
6. In our case 36 is an exit in the list so the output will be true and you are printing the statement. It will perform the operation that removed 36 from the list and print the true or false operation. It removed the 36 so it is true. now the list will be growablelist =[5,64], remove object related

   ```
     print(growablelist.remove(36));
   ```
7. removeAt(int index)the item at a given index in a List and you are printing the statement.  remove the item at index '0'. now now the list will be growablelist =[64]. removeAt is index related.

   ```
     print(growablelist.removeAt(0));
   ```